# Xamarin Android TCP Client

Tags: c#, xamarin, tcp, client

I am making a Xamarin Android TCP Client App which talks to a C# Winform TCP Server.

The client can **connect** and **sent text** to the server.

But I cannot **receive** text from the server.

The Server works fully with its C# Winform TCP Client

```
        private void buttonConnect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                if (buttonConnect.Text == "Connect")
                {
                    client = new TcpClient("192.168.1.185", 88); 
                    Toast.MakeText(this, "Connected", ToastLength.Short).Show();
                    buttonConnect.Text = "Dis-Connect";
                    textReceive.Text = null;
                    buttonSend.Enabled = true;
                    clientReceive(); //Starts Receiving When Connected
                }
                else
                {
                    buttonConnect.Text = "Connect";
                    Toast.MakeText(this, "Dis-Connected", ToastLength.Short).Show();
                    client.GetStream().Close();
                    client.Close();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Toast.MakeText(this, ex.Message, ToastLength.Short).Show();
            }
        }
```

```
      private void clientReceive()
      {
          try
          {
              stream = client.GetStream(); //Gets The Stream of The Connection
              new Thread(() => // Thread (like Timer)
                {
                    // while ((i = stream.Read(datalength, 0, 4)) != 0)
                    while(client.Connected)
                     {
                        byte[] data = new byte[BitConverter.ToInt32(datalength, 0)]; 
                        stream.Read(data, 0, data.Length); 
                        this.RunOnUiThread(() => this.textReceive.Text = textReceive.Text + 
                     (Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data)) +
                     System.Environment.NewLine);
                     }
               }).Start(); // Start the Thread
          }
          catch (Exception ex)
          {
              Toast.MakeText(this, ex.Message, ToastLength.Short).Show();
          }
      }
```

Comment: Do you have any specific reason why you want to use raw TCP? TCP is a low level protocol that require *you* to deal with things like message framing. You cannot just make a single read and assume your complete text will be transferred . A higher level protocol like http, grcp, mqtt etc will be much easier to use since it allow you to send *messages*.

Comment: I am looking into MQTT, but for now, it does need to be TCP

Comment: Is there any log about this problem? Can you share it here?

Comment: Most protocols uses TCP. But you **will** use a protocol on top of TCP. Either a third party protocol, or one you create yourself. Chances are a third party protocol and library will be much better designed, faster, and reliable, than the thing you would create yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I checked the TCP Winform Client
and found that the  byte[] data, was the problem.
Fully working now

`private void buttonConnect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     try
     {
         if (buttonConnect.Text == "Connect")
         {
             client = new TcpClient("192.168.1.186", 88); //Trys to Connect
             Toast.MakeText(this, "Connected", ToastLength.Short).Show();
             buttonConnect.Text = "Dis-Connect";
             textReceive.Text = null;
             buttonSend.Enabled = true;
             new Thread(() =>
             {
                 stream = client.GetStream(); 
                 while (client.Connected)
                 {
                     byte[] data = new byte[1024]; //fixed
                     stream.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
                     string output = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data);
                      RunOnUiThread(() =>
                         {
                             this.textReceive.Text = this.textReceive.Text
                                               + output
                                               + System.Environment.NewLine;
                         });
                 }
             }).Start();
         }
         else
         {
             buttonConnect.Text = "Connect";
             Toast.MakeText(this, "Dis-Connected", ToastLength.Short).Show();
             client.GetStream().Close();
             client.Close();
         }
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
         Toast.MakeText(this, ex.Message, ToastLength.Short).Show();
     }
 }`